# Combinatorial Optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, selection, combinations

An example of my dataset looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(cbind(a = c(1,3,5), b = c(4,1,7), c = c(1,9,10)))
y = c(8, 9, 20)
```

**I want to find out the best combination of a, b, and c that maximizes the correlation between the sum of selected columns and y.**

For example, find the strongest correlation among all these combinations:

```
cor(df$a, y)
cor(df$b, y)
cor(df$c, y)
cor(df$a+df$b, y)
cor(df$a+df$c, y)
cor(df$b+df$c, y)
cor(df$a+df$b+df$c, y)
```

My current method is:

```
combination = list()
for(i in 1:3){combination[[i]]=c(NA,1)}
names(combination) = c("a", "b", "c") 
combi = arrange(expand.grid(combination), a)

combi = mutate(combi, cor = NA)

for (i in 1:2^3){
  x = as.numeric(combi[i,])
  col = x*c(1:3)
  col = col[!is.na(col)]

  if(length(col)>1){
     t = rowSums(df[, col])
     combi[i, 4] = cor(t,y)
  }

  if(length(col)==1){
     t = df[, col]
     combi[i, 4] = cor(t,y)
  }

  if(length(col)==0){
     combi[i, 4] = NA
  }

}
```

Is there an easy way of evaluating all possible combinations? When the total number of columns increases, it becomes really painful to find all combinations. What kind of strategy should I use here to find the best combination(just a local optimization) within limited steps? How about forward/backward stepwise selection?

There is no model in this case. By saying forward/backward stepwise selection, I mean a similar method like what people do with regression models:
Instead of searching for all possible combinations of columns all at once, start with each column individually and find the one that has the strongest correlation. Then, only consider combinations that include this column.

Thank you so much for any advice!

Comment: You can't ask for packages on Stack Overflow. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Possible duplicate: [r All combinations of all sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17817897/903061).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "forward/backward/stepwise selection". You could use, e.g., `MASS::stepAIC` to do linear model selection, but that would be linear combinations without your constraint that all coefficients are 1.

Comment: I think the key question here is not to find all combinations, but a strategy to effectively evaluate all combinations in limited steps.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there are packages around to do the whole evaluation, but the looping over all possible cases can be made more efficient with the use of combn:

```
# basic data
df = data.frame(cbind(a = c(1,3,5), b = c(4,1,7), c = c(1,9,10)))
y = c(8, 9, 20)

# do single correlations first, since the following code with apply refuses single columns
cors<-data.frame(m=NA,cc=NA)  # define cors to collect results

for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  cors[i,1]<-1
  cors[i,2]<-cor(df[,i],y)
}

# the following code uses combn to find all combinations and perform a function on them, with correlations as result. These are stored in cors

for (m in 2:ncol(df)){
  cv<-combn(ncol(df),m,FUN=function(x) cor(apply(df[,x],1,sum),y))
  cors[(i+1):(i+length(cv)),2]<-cv
  cors[(i+1):(i+length(cv)),1]<-m
  i<-i+length(cv)
}

print(cors)
```

Which yields:

```
  m        cc
1 1 0.9011271
2 1 0.8260332
3 1 0.6444459
4 2 0.9819805
5 2 0.7317957
6 2 0.9385110
7 3 0.9299975
```

Where m gives you the number of columns combined,and cc the correlation. With some improvement, you could also preserve the composition of the combination in the same data frame, but you can also first pick out the maximum and then find out what the combination is that yielded the maximum (in this case the first value with m=2, which is given as `combn(ncol(df),m)[,1]`)