# Create combination of all elements in a list

Tags: r, combinations, combn

I am creating a function that requires the user to enter the input variables and then the function creates **all possible combinations (of varying lengths)** of those input parameters. Lets say input variables are "A", "B", and "C".

| Combination # | Input1 | Input2 | Input3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C |
| 2 | A | B |  |
| 3 | A |  |  |
| 4 |  | B | C |
| 5 |  | B |  |
| 6 | A |  | C |
| 7 |  |  | C |

I want R to form all possible combinations of A, B, and C and create a data frame for it. For example:

Any idea how I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicates - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953588/unordered-combinations-of-all-lengths/49591309 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817897/all-combinations-of-all-sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c(TRUE,FALSE)

expand.grid(x,x,x) %>%
  filter(rowSums(.) != 0) %>%
  mutate(Var1 = ifelse(Var1, "A", ""),
         Var2 = ifelse(Var2, "B", ""),
         Var3 = ifelse(Var3, "C", "")) %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column()

  rowname Var1 Var2 Var3
1       1    A    B    C
2       2         B    C
3       3    A         C
4       4              C
5       5    A    B     
6       6         B     
7       7    A
```

## function

```
func <- function(input){
  n <- length(input)
  x <- c(TRUE,FALSE)
  
  y <- expand.grid(rep(list(x),n)) %>%
    filter(rowSums(.) != 0)
  
  for (i in 1:length(input)){
    y[,i] [y[,i]] <- input[i]
    y[,i][y[,i] != input[i]] <- ""
    
  }
  
  y %>%
    rownames_to_column()
}


inp <- c("A", "B", "C")
func(inp) 

  rowname Var1 Var2 Var3
1       1    A    B    C
2       2         B    C
3       3    A         C
4       4              C
5       5    A    B     
6       6         B     
7       7    A
```

Comment: Your question assumes that only 3 input variables are given. I am trying to create a function for n-input variables. Any idea how I can develop the function for any number of input variables? Thanks for the input!

Comment: @kav I add generalized function version.

Comment: @kav I did a little update to function that removed input `n`.  It wasn't needed in function. Sorry for confusing.